# The file created with Selenium in Python does not work when converted to exe

Tags: python, selenium

I've programmed a basic test automation with Selenium in Python. This project contain only one `.py` file. I converted it to `.exe` and when I try to run it on  another computer(which doesnt have python or selenium) it doesn't work. I also tried to locate on the other computer webdrivers file to the same path just as my computer. Also it didn't work. This was my first attempt. Then I searched on the internet and some solutions were using `auto-py-to-exe` with add location of selenium with add binaries on the `py-to-exe`. I also tried and result wasnt change. This is a screenshot of my program.

[image]

As far as I understand, it's about being Selenium is not in the PATH. But I added to the PATH. IDK why it says this?

Answer (score 0):

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) can be used to convert Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX. It is one of the recommended converters.

Package the chromedriver with your python library and provide its path in the python file.

for example:

```
import os
if os.name == "nt":  #for windows
    os.environ["chromedriver"]="C:\user\chromedriver.exe"  #adjust path as per OS for chromedriver
elif os.name == "posix":  #for linux
    os.environ["chromedriver"]="/root/user/chromedriver.exe"  #adjust path as per OS for chromedriver
```